# vba code to copy specific columns from worksheet1 to worksheet2

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code to copy data from sheet1 to sheet 2. All columns are getting selected, How can I modify to pick column A, I, and M only:

```
Sub NewSheetData() 
    With Application 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 
        .EnableEvents = False 
    End With 

    Dim Rng As Range 

    Set Rng = Range([A1], Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 

    On Error Resume Next 

    With Rng 
        .AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="*TC*", Operator:=xlOr 
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 
        .AutoFilter 

    End With 

    On Error Goto 0 

    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an individual Copy Paste like this:

```
With Rng
    .AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="*TC*", Operator:=xlOr
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("A1").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("I1").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("M1").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Edit:
you can also try:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```